# Texture losing binding

Tags: c++, opengl

I am losing the binding to a texture. Generally my code works but it seems that in some circumstances the generate function will successfully create and upload the texture to graphics memory but in the main loop `glIsTexture()` will return false.

There is only one thread that touches OpenGL.

The following is pseudo code as this is part of a much larger project and far too complicated to go into details here. I am not looking for syntax checking of my code, I need some help understanding what could cause this to happen and how to debug it.

Main loop:

```
while(generateTexture(texture_id, sequence_number))
{
  if(glIsTexture(texture_id))
  {
    cerr << "Got texture!\n";
    // (Do something with texture here)
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_id);
  }
  else
    cerr << "Bad texture\n";
}
```

Function:

```
void generateTexture(GLuint &texID, int number)
{
  // (Generate texture here)

  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  glGenTextures(1, &texID);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0,
               GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data);

  if(!glIsTexture(texID))
  {
    cerr << "Failed to upload texture " << texID << " for number " << number << "\n";
  }
  else
    cerr << " -> uploaded to texture " << texID << "\n";
}
```

Comment: There is a paranthesis missing after `if(glIsTexture(texture_id)` and also in `while(generateTexture(texture_id, sequence_number)`. Also `generateTexture` is `void`, so you cannot use its return as a `bool` in the while-condition. I'm guessing its closing bracket is also only missing as a typo.

Comment: And `if(!glIsTexture(tex))` should probably be `if(!glIsTexture(texID))`.

Comment: `glIsTexture` doesn't require texture to be bound, so it isn't about binding. Code in question contains so many syntax errors it is clear it is not the real code, and hence there is no point in trying to find mistake in it (e.g. it may no longer be there). Ordinary C/C++ debugger, [apitrace](https://apitrace.github.io/) or [renderdoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc) may all be helpful here. How is `generateTexture` declared? Is it possible that you're creating too many textures (as it is generated in loop endlessly?)?

Comment: Why do you check the success of your data submission with `glIsTexture`?! You should check whether `glTexImage2D` has completed successfully or not - that is the command . `glIsTexture` only gives you information about whether a name you pass to it refers to an actual texture object - this is the case if `glBindTexture()` returns without error for some *target* and some previously unused *name* returned by `glGenTextures()` or for one more names returned by `glCreateTextures`.

Comment: @thokra I only introduced `glIsTexture` to help debug the code. How do I properly check that my texture is in memory ? `glTexImage2D` does not return a value. And why would `glIsTexture` fail in my main loop, given it returns true in the function ?

Comment: @koan: Just check whether your commands return without any errors (with `glGetError()`) or (preferably) if your debug message callback (if any) is invoked with an error message - that's it. There is no reason to assume that something went wrong when no errors are reported and if something still went wrong, you have little chance of finding out *what* went wrong without trial and error.

Your above code *will never fail* - at least not in regards to `glIsTexture` - you either need to give us more context or we can't help you.